# Auto reply that ignores certain email addresses

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, gmail-api

I use Google script for my out of office as I want it to run on certain days.

It works - but a little too well.

Question is, can I make it ignore certain senders? For examples, sender addresses that begin "noreply" or "no_reply", or senders from certain domains? My existing code is as below:

```
function autoReply() {
   var interval = 1; // if the script runs every 5 minutes; change otherwise
   var daysOff = [2,4]; // 1=Mo, 2=Tu, 3=We, 4=Th, 5=Fr, 6=Sa, 0=Su
   var message = "Thank you for your message.\n\ \n\I am currently out of office";
   var date = new Date();
  var day = date.getDay();
   if (daysOff.indexOf(day) > -1) {
      var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
      var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox after:' + timeFrom);
      for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
        threads[i].reply(message);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation - general idea:

- You can create an array of email usernames that you would like to exclude:

  `var exclude = ['noreply','no_reply','username1'];`
- Check if the sender of the message belongs to that list and send a reply message only to the email addresses that don't:

  ```
  if(!exclude.includes(threads[i].getMessages()[0].getFrom().split("@")[0])){
        threads[i].reply(message);
    }
  ```
- As you can see I use `getFrom().split("@")[0]` to isolate the username from the email. For example, if you receive an email from `noreply@whatever.com`, the script will check if `noreply` is in the `exclude` array.

---

### Solution 1 - check only the first message:

In this solution I am checking if the sender of the first message in the thread is not part of the username list:

```
function autoReply() {
   var interval = 1; // if the script runs every 5 minutes; change otherwise
   var daysOff = [2,4]; // 1=Mo, 2=Tu, 3=We, 4=Th, 5=Fr, 6=Sa, 0=Su
   var exclude = ['noreply','no_reply','username1'];
   var message = "Thank you for your message.\n\ \n\I am currently out of office";
   var date = new Date();
  var day = date.getDay();
   if (daysOff.indexOf(day) > -1) {
      var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
      var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox after:' + timeFrom);
      for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
        if(!exclude.includes(threads[i].getMessages()[0].getFrom().split("@")[0])){
        threads[i].reply(message);
        }
      }
   }
}
```

The issue with this approach is that if the first message comes from a `noreply` account but the second one comes from an actual person's email, the script won't send a noreply email. If you don't want this behaviour, then use the next approach (solution 2).

### Solution 2 - check all messages:

This is a more generic approach. We check on the sender for each message and for every thread. If the sender is not part of the `exclude` array, send a reply email to the thread. After you find at least one sender that is not in the `exclude` array you break the message loop so you won't send the same email multiple times for the same thread:

```
function autoReply() {
   var interval = 1; // if the script runs every 5 minutes; change otherwise
   var daysOff = [2,4]; // 1=Mo, 2=Tu, 3=We, 4=Th, 5=Fr, 6=Sa, 0=Su
   var exclude = ['noreply','no_reply','username1'];
   var exclude_doms = ['domain1','domain2'];
   var message = "Thank you for your message.\n\ \n\I am currently out of office";
   var date = new Date();
  var day = date.getDay();
   if (daysOff.indexOf(day) > -1) {
      var timeFrom = Math.floor(date.valueOf()/1000) - 60 * interval;
      var threads = GmailApp.search('is:inbox after:' + timeFrom);
      for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
        var messages = threads[i].getMessages();
        for (var j = 0; j < messages.length; j++){
        if(!exclude.includes(messages[j].getFrom().split("@")[0])
          && !exclude_doms.includes(messages[j].getFrom().split("@")[1])
          ){
            threads[i].reply(message);
            break;
         }
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Or, to be honest, just train people out of expecting an immediate reply to every email (that's not how email works!) then turn the out-of-office off. Much healthier and less error-prone to boot. If you need to signify to others in your organisation that you are not working that day, surely there is some central calendar for this task?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Thanks for your input. But I don't  think you can select particular days as days off. I assume many people nowdays work part time and out of office for particular days can be kind handy :)

Comment: Every management system I've used at work has allowed you to indicate when you are unavailable, be it via a one-time event or a recurring (e.g. weekly) event, like any other calendar .. or they've had a digital leave booking system that also shows when people are not expected to be working per contract. But if you don't have that, then I can understand why you might feel the need to fall back on something else!

Comment: This is Gmail and I think it does not support this functionality as a built in option. @AsteroidsWithWings

Comment: Yeah, I'm not saying to find it in Gmail, I'm saying your business should have a proper employee management system to do things like this.

Comment: @Marios brilliant, thank you. I was so nearly there and yet would never have found my way to it, much appreciated.

Comment: @Marios Can I ask, will the split allow domains to be added to the exclude list? My bot frequently gets in out of office loops with one particular service provider whose domain I'd therefore like to exclude. Thanks in advance.